# python mysql в запросе insert кавычки из escape_srting

Tags: mysql, python, utf-8

В некой строке содержатся кавычки и другие знаки (аоЭ"пал), а так же текст с русскими символами:

```
strinnng = "аоЭ\"пал"
```

Пытаюсь заэкранировать эти знаки (в коннекторе _mysql_connector есть такая функция). На выходе получается байтовая строка почему то, что дальше с ней делать? У меня выходят ошибки =((((

```
tyu = cnx.escape_string(strinnng)
```

Затем делаю запрос в бд

```
cnx.query('INSERT INTO test (title) VALUES ("%s")' % tyu)
```

Помогите кто знает?

Answer (score 1):

В экранировании sql-запросов есть свои подводные камни и если делать это руками, можно потратить много времени на решение подобных проблем.

Лучше использовать sqlalchemy: она тоже умеет выполнять "сырые" запросы в обход ORM, при этом экранируя их. [Пример из документации](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/tutorial.html#using-text).

А ещё лучше использовать ORM – полностью абстрагироваться от работы с sql-запросом. [ORM-туториал из документации sqlalchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html).